# Kernel Kmeans formula

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, kernel

I'm trying to implement the Kernel Kmeans algorithm but I struggle with the following formula :

[image]

Let's say I have a case in one dimension with three points : 1, 5, 9. Let's say I want two clusters. Then let's say I choose 1 and 9 as centroids for the start. How did I compute the distance for the first point (1) ? Imagine I choose the linear kernel (which is a simple dot product between vectors). I have tried the following :

$$(1 \cdot 1) + (9 \cdot 9) - 2  (1 \cdot 9)$$

I'm not sure to understand well the terms of the formula. For the first term, I understand it as the dot product between the point and itself. For the second term, I understand it as the dot product between the cluster center and itself. And for the third term, I understand it as the dot product between the point and the center. What is wrong in my calculation and how I correct it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit difficult, but I think I have found a way to implement this formula. Hope this answer will help those struggling with the implementation of Kernel Kmeans algorithm. Here is a working formula for the Kernel Kmeans :

[image]

If I'm right, the main idea behind this formula is to minimize the variance inside clusters. Note that there is no need to calculate the centroids, all the calculations are done in the high dimensional space using a Kernel function. The steps of the algorithm can be describe as :

1. Initialize random centers to produce the first assignments of the inputs
2. Use the formula described above to calculate the new clusters assignments
3. Repeat step 2 till convergence

I think the formula implementation roughly looks like this in Javascript :

```
for (var i = 0; i < kMeans; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < Data.length; j++) {
            var Indexes = []
            for (var k = 0; k < Assignement.length; k++) {
                if (Assignement[k] === i) {
                    Indexes.push(1)
                } else {
                    Indexes.push(0)
                }
            }

            var SecondSum = 0
          
            for (var k = 0; k < SimilarityMatrix.length; k++) {
                for (var l = 0; l < SimilarityMatrix.length; l++) {
                    SecondSum += Indexes[k] * Indexes[l] * SimilarityMatrix[k].flat()[l]
                }
            }                

            var FirstSum = 0

            for (var k = 0; k < SimilarityMatrix.length; k++) {
               FirstSum += Indexes[k] * SimilarityMatrix[k].flat()[j]
            }

            var SumIndexes = Indexes.reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a + b
            })

            DistancesToClusters[i].push(SimilarityMatrix[j].flat()[j] - 2 * FirstSum / SumIndexes + SecondSum / Math.pow(SumIndexes,2))
        }
    }
```

Here is the result on a toy dataset :

[image]

Here is some very helpful ressources and examples of implementations (mainly in Python and R) :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsLjxzoKbOI&t=2406s&ab_channel=MilesChen
- https://git01lab.cs.univie.ac.at/osterj97/oster-bachelor-thesis/-/tree/main/kkmeans
- [https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~nir.schwartz/courses/unsupervised/mykkmeans.html](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Enir.schwartz/courses/unsupervised/mykkmeans.html)
- https://github.com/Javcm/Kernel-k-means
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVhtchqHlHs&t=20s&ab_channel=ArdianUmam

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the formula for your chosen linear kernel with dot product $K(x_n, \mu_k)=x_n \cdot \mu_k$. In your case you seem to try to compute the sum of kernel functions for the first point $x_1=1$ as part of the objective function for your kernel K-means algorithm and you have 2 centroids for the start. So you first only need 2 terms to compute the distance for the first point as $K(x_1, \mu_1)=1$ and $K(x_1, \mu_2)=9$, not your 3 terms which is not a linear kernel for your (linear) kernel trick, but the square of Euclidean distance in the original input space. Then of course similarly you need to do the same for the other remaining 2 points.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. It's clear for the linear case. But what happens next if I decide to use a non-linear Kernel ? For example the Radial Basis function. What kind of computation I should do to calculate the distance between a point and a centroid ? I have tried the above calculation but it doesn't work

Comment: IMO you'd better accept this answer if you yourself claimed '*It's clear for the linear case*' and start a new question for nonlinear kernels such as RBFs since your main picture containing formulas are dot product linear kernels. Having said that, there's no essential structural difference for RBF nor other nonlinear kernel K-means algo, RBF kernels are just $K_{i,j}=\exp(-\|\mathbf{x_i}-\mathbf{x_j}\|^2/2\sigma^2)$ instead of simple dot product here. Your kernel K-means objective function is still the sum of all data points' kernelized 'distance' to all the centroids.